# Getting the nova compute state to be enabled and up for kolla-openstack

Tags: openstack, ubuntu-22.04, openstack-nova, kolla-ansible, openstack-horizon

Following this set of instructions: https://kifarunix.com/deploy-all-in-one-openstack-with-kolla-ansible-on-ubuntu-22-04/, I was able to get The Kolla OpenStack All-In-One deployment to pass the prechecks, deploy, and post-deploy scripts. Everything appears to be working great.

I am able to log into the web insterface at http://172.25.11.10 using the admin password created in /etc/kolla/passwords.yml.

However, when I try to configure the Admin / Host Aggregates settings, I find there is no Availability Zone set. No matter what I do, I am unable to bring up  the nova zone for the nova-compute binary.

```
(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$ openstack compute service list --service nova-compute
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Binary       | Host      | Zone | Status   | State | Updated At                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
| b48f552c-38e1-4723-97b4-04c9e132f4a2 | nova-compute | openstack | nova | disabled | down  | 2023-11-28T17:49:06.000000 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
```

No problem, I'll enable this on the CLI.

```
(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$ openstack compute service set --enable --up openstack nova-compute
```

I then list the nova-compute service:

```
(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$ openstack compute service list --service nova-compute
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Binary       | Host      | Zone | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| b48f552c-38e1-4723-97b4-04c9e132f4a2 | nova-compute | openstack | nova | enabled | down  | 2023-11-28T21:52:50.000000 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

The status is enabled, but the state remains down. I have read through and followed all other suggestions related to this issue, but cannot seem to pin it down.

```
(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$ openstack service list
+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| ID                               | Name      | Type           |
+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 712f40a19657425ea999259495f58903 | placement | placement      |
| 9dde759fae994e73aa1d86981f50d8d5 | neutron   | network        |
| c6f618ff6faf451b98aa63410784b179 | nova      | compute        |
| c76a85490a8543dd8b39e2078a4f2e3a | heat-cfn  | cloudformation |
| c81f5abec7cd4494baff14923ad0faf9 | keystone  | identity       |
| d19331b13f5942899c2e83a547bdb6f5 | heat      | orchestration  |
| d91e0ea9dcfb4efbbb42588a9d42e5a9 | glance    | image          |
+----------------------------------+-----------+----------------+

(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$ openstack compute service list
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Binary         | Host      | Zone     | Status   | State | Updated At                 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
| 2300a984-d142-48db-9fc7-eda35911bae0 | nova-conductor | openstack | internal | enabled  | up    | 2023-11-28T21:55:22.000000 |
| b48f552c-38e1-4723-97b4-04c9e132f4a2 | nova-compute   | openstack | nova     | disabled | down  | 2023-11-28T21:53:51.000000 |
| f2c20f5e-6157-4485-9d15-31bbc801d2c5 | nova-scheduler | openstack | internal | enabled  | up    | 2023-11-28T21:55:21.000000 |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
(kolla-openstack) lab@openstack:~$
```

I was able to successfully configure the extra drive using the `sudo vgs` command, which is allocated to the `cinder-volumes` LVM.

Anyone have any ideas on how to bring the nova-compute Availability Zones online?

Thanks in advance. And, apologies for this being a newbie question.

Comment: Check the nova-compute.log (or similar, I'm not familiar with kolla) on the host, it should show why the service doesn't start.